# Mod Rewrite with ? in url

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I have a site I am working on and just did the mod rewrite so the the url cuadmemo.com/posts.php?title=abctitle writes to cuadmemo.com/abctitle.html

The issue I am having is when you have a title with a ? mark in it. You click the link

```
http://www.cuadmemo.com/Are You Doing All You Can to Protect Your Members From Wire Fraud?.html
```

and it shows as not found? I know that the ? is what causes the issue. I am writing in php and have the links in this format (pulling from a database)

Below is the php code I am using to write the statement.

```
echo "<a name='description' href='http://www.cuadmemo.com/{$row_oneBack['title']}.html'>". $row_oneBack['title'] . '</a>';
```

The rewrite code I am using is

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html /posts.php?title=$1
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a very web-safe url. You should do something like this instead;
Are_You_Doing_All_You_Can_to_Protect_Your_Members_From_Wire_Fraud.html

Comment: Right originally I was pulling it from the id in the database which was written like cuadmemo.com/posts.php?id=123 but wanted it to be more like a wordpress blog that would rewrite it to show the title in url instead. wasn't sure how to go that route. So used cuadmemo.com/posts.php?title=whatevertitlenameis

Comment: @StevoBot That's a good idea, however you should instead do something like this to keep the ID in the rewrite;

example.com/post/123/TITLEWHATEVER.html that way you can use any character after IDNumber

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a question mark `?` apache is tricked into thinking that you are trying to have something like `$_GET['.html']` Therefore, your url is cut.

It seems your CMS/php is looking at `$_GET['title']`. If you want to have questionmarks, you should have it look at and parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

You could take this:

```
# infile .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

and then look for your query like so:

```
http://example.com/test/page?is=ok&has=get-params

// infile: index.php
// var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// you will get string '/test/page?is=ok&has=get-params' (length=41)
```

Comment: So when I pull the info from the database I should then pass it over to the new page with a    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?

Comment: If you choose to remain with your way of link creation, then using the above code you will have your `title` inside `$title = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`